# Adding a Large XML Element to an XML File Always Fails

Tags: xml, installation, nsis

My NSIS installer is attempting to add some XML to an existing XML file.

**My Problem:** Its failing to add node/element to the file because, I think, there are too many sub-elements inside the node/element.

How can I add this XML element to an existing XML file?

**NOTE** If I decrease the length of the string OVERRIDES_TEXT by about half, then the code correctly adds the node to the XML file. Anything longer and it fails. Is it possible to write the contents(not text but sub-elements) of a element/node in 2 go's?

```
${xml::LoadFile} "${xmlFileName}" $R0
${xml::GotoPath} "${elementPath}" $R0
${xml::CreateNode} '<Overrides>${OVERRIDES_TEXT}</Overrides>' $R0
${xml::InsertAfterNode} $R0 $R1  # always fails here $R1 = -1

# below is the string that causes the error
!define OVERRIDES_TEXT "<Override>\
                <Key>EXDS_CUSTOMISATION_REVISION</Key>\
                <Value>1</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>CUSTOMER_USER_4D</Key>\
                <Value>C:\12d\10.00\Customers\EXDS_Customisation\EXDS_User</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>CUSTOMER_LIB_4D</Key>\
                <Value>C:\12d\10.00\Customers\EXDS_Customisation\EXDS_User_Lib</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>USER_4D</Key>\
                <Value>C:\12d\10.00\User</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>USER_LIB_4D</Key>\
                <Value>C:\12d\10.00\User_Lib</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>EXDS_USER_LIB</Key>\
                <Value></Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>EXDS_USER</Key>\
                <Value></Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>VERSION_12D_MODEL</Key>\
                <Value>10.0</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>CPATH</Key>\
                <Value>$$CUSTOMER_LIB_4D:$$CUSTOMER_USER_4D:$$USER_LIB_4D:$$USER_4D:$$LIB_4D:$$SET_UPS_4D</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>AUTHORIZATION_4D</Key>\
                <Value>C:\12d\10.00\nodes.4d</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>USE_NAMES_COMMENT_4D</Key>\
                <Value>1</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>FILE_READ_ADD_TO_VIEW_4D</Key>\
                <Value>1</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>GENIO_WILDCARD_4D</Key>\
                <Value>*.inp</Value>\
                <State>1</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>RUN_MACROS_FILE_4D</Key>\
                <Value>$$USER\macros.4d</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>PROJECT_DETAILS_4D</Key>\
                <Value>$$USER\project_details.dtl</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>REPORT_HEADER_4D</Key>\
                <Value>1</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>AUTO_TIN_SYNC_4D</Key>\
                <Value>1</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>AUTO_MODEL_SYNC_4D</Key>\
                <Value>1</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>SHARE_CHECK_INTERVAL_4D</Key>\
                <Value>300</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>SHARED_ELEMENT_COLOUR_4D</Key>\
                <Value>blue</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>SHARING_ELEMENT_COLOUR_4D</Key>\
                <Value>red</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>DEFAULT_PLAN_PLOT_SCALE_4D</Key>\
                <Value>500</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>DWG_PLOT_SEED_FILE_4D</Key>\
                <Value>$$USER\EXDS_Acad_Plot_Template.dwt</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>DEFAULT_RASTER_DPI_4D</Key>\
                <Value>600</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>OPENGL_VIEW_BACKING_STORE_4D</Key>\
                <Value>2</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>MULTI_LINE_TEXT_4D</Key>\
                <Value>1</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>NEW_MTF_EDITOR_AUTOPAN_DEFAULT_4D</Key>\
                <Value>1</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>WINDOWS_VEHICLE_PATH_4D</Key>\
                <Value>C:\Apps\VPath</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>chainage_equality_4d</Key>\
                <Value>1</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>XML_4D</Key>\
                <Value>1</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>\
            <Override>\
                <Key>USE_V10_BOXING_CALCS_4D</Key>\
                <Value>1</Value>\
                <State>0</State>\
            </Override>"
```

Comment: Does it work if you make XML shorter and not multiline?

Comment: @PetrAbdulin yes it does if I make the XML shorter, I'll try multiline.

Comment: I tried making the string one line - not multiline - the same error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this syntax is correct:

```
${xml::InsertAfterNode} $R0 $R1
```

souldn't it be

```
${xml::InsertAfterNode} "$R0" $R1
```

?

Comment: thansk for the advice. I tried what you said(passing as a string) but it still failed. Any ideas whats going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting the NSIS string length limit, try adding one `<Override>` node at the time with the XML plugin...